# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function in laravel blade template

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-blade

I am trying to show bootstrap modal on button click like this:

```
    @extends('layouts.main')
    @section('body')
        <div>
          <button type="button" onClick="buttonClick()"></button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">  
              modal content.........
        </div>
     
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        function buttonClick() {
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
        }
        </script>
    @endsection
```

but getting following error:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

The main layout file contains another file:

@include('layouts.scripts')

which in turn loads bootsrap/jquery stripts in following order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery.actual.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/chosen.jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

any idea what could be wrong??

Comment: Looks like bootstrap.min.js is not loaded. Have you checked the browser inspector console to notice if all scripts are fully loaded?

Comment: masterguru yes sources does show bootstrap.min.js loaded.

Comment: What is jquery.actual.min.js? If that's another instance of jQuery then it will remove the bootstrap methods which were loaded

Comment: I removed jquery.actual.min.js still getting same error

Comment: I tried jQuery.noConflict(); then I get no error but modal won't show.

Comment: Turns out jQuery.noConflict(); actually solved the problem because it was version conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Try include bootstrap script before JQuery script